# How to define mailer configuration in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-4.2

How to define mailer configuration in rails engine. Like I have a main rails application and rails engine mounted in rails app as gem.

My main app has its own mail setting defined in environment file. But I want to define separate mail setting for rails engine. How can I do this?